# Data Algorithm (Python)

Tags: python, algorithm, queue

will anyone help me execute this piece of code and help me understand it in a simple way. Thanks

```
values - Queue()
for i in range ( 32 ) :
    if i %3 == 0 :
        values.enqueue(i)
```

Comment: What don't you understand? Let's start there.

Comment: I dont really get the second and third line

Comment: The second line is performing a loop. In plain English you could translate as: "For every number from 0 to 32, I want to represent it as 'i'". The third is only adding items it the queue if i mod 3 is 0. If you're not familiar with modulo, it is saying it will only execute if i / 3 has a remainder of 0. In other words, if the number is divisible by 3.

Comment: Alright so it will only store the values of numbers that are dividable by 3 and ignore the rest between 0-32?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct.

Comment: So the last line of code just adds the values dividable by 3 to the que?

Comment: Well this implementation of a queue is not one I'm familiar with (thy python queue module uses 'put' instead of 'enqueue'), but I'd assume so.

Comment: So how would it look like if i were to hand execute the code

Answer (score -1):

So if by values - Queue() you mean values = Queue().
Its very simple a queue data structure uses the FIFO method first in first out.Here is how you would do it:

```
values = []
for i in range (1,32+1) :
    if i % 3 == 0 :
        #Inserts at head
        values.insert(0,i)
print(values)
#removes first element inserted in queue
values.pop()
print(values)
```

The `i % 3 == 0` is just checking if the number is divisible by 3.

If you want more references: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/queue-data-structure/